# Узнать, содержит ли родительский div класс

Tags: jquery

Есть такая конструкция

```
<div class="cl1 cl2">
  <div>
    ....
    <span>
            <span class="menu-click">+</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно узнать, если ли среди дивов-предков `span.menu-click` див с классом `cl2`.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью метода [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) :

```
 $('.menu-click').parents('div.cl2').length>0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/z7uZP/

Comment: а `.length>0` зачем нужно?

Comment: потому-что parents всегда возвращает объект коллекции jQuery и определить пустой он или нет можно только с помощью length вот пример  когда неправильно используется: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/z7uZP/3/

Comment: ну и конечно я использовал `$('.menu-click')` для  примера, в реальной жизни вы видимо будете это использовать в обработчике события, т.е. вам нужно использовать $(this) я бы вообще что-бы не париться сделал 

    $(document).on('click','div.cl2 span.menu-click',function)

и тогда бы этот вопрос вообще не встал.